# Dependence of stability of nucleus on the packing fraction

Tags: nuclear-physics

How does the packing fraction of a nucleus affect the stability of the nucleus? A true and false based statement question came in a exam I gave, and it stated the statement "The stability of a nucleus is inversely proportional to its packing fraction" to be "True". Google search doesn't reveal any helpful articles, though I found one handout which stated

$$ \text{Packing Fraction} = \frac{\text{Actual Isotopic Mass - Mass Number}}{\text{Mass Number}} $$

and that the more negative the packing fraction, the more stable would the nuclei be. Although the relationship with stability does make sense by following this definition of the *packing fraction*, I do not understand how this relates (if it is supposed to be related) to the conventional packing fraction studied in solid state chemistry. Any help or references to study this from would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the 'packing fraction' here has nothing to do with reality, but has been constructed from a binding energy point of view solely. Connections to solid state crystal packing fractions is tenuous at best.